# Unable to jump to new page using the jquery scroll to

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using local scroll to from http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Now my problem is I have to navigate to new html page. I tried using test.html#section2 but it only scrolls locally.  Can you tell me what am I doing wrong

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav, #footer-nav').onePageNav({
    begin: function() {
    console.log('start')
    },
    end: function() {
    console.log('stop')
    },
    changeHash: true
  });
  });
 </script>
```

[image]

This is my website http://www.spheretekk.com/indus/
if you go to the footer section and see my screenshot where I said I want it to open a new page and then jump to the ID specified.

I manage to create a fiddle here it it
http://jsfiddle.net/U8v2y/

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are looking for?

Comment: Make a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ . Also explain more about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript function to scroll

In document ready function get the element id by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   scrollme(hash);
);
```

Add these function to script

```
function scrollme(id)
{
     var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
     var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset-100}, 1000, function() {

          });
}
function scrollableElement(els)
{
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
}
```